# Is it possible to have Jenkins workflows with an overlapping/shared stage?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

This question concerns use of the Jenkins Workflow plugin and "synchronizing" a stage amongst independent jobs.

We have a generic workflow for multiple projects with steps:

1. build project
2. push project to test environment
3. run (long) end-to-end test suite
4. push project to production

Step 3 runs a long time. If multiple projects are built and pushed to the test environment within the same window of time, we'd like to only run once the end-to-end test suite.

Can we have the jobs some how synchronize on step 3?

Answer (score 0):

The desired orchestration can be achieved by make Step 3 a `build` action. I.e.

`build end-to-end-tests`

Where `end-to-end-tests` is a job dedicated to running the slow end-to-end tests.

Adding a `Quiet period` to `end-to-end-tests` supports the goal of "collecting" projects updated within a time period to end-to-end test. That is, if project A and B are pushed to the test environment with `Quiet period` seconds, then `end-to-end-tests` runs only once.

Answer (score 0):

[JENKINS-30269](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30269) might be helpful, but your use case is indeed subtly different from the usual one that RFE would solve; you really seem to need a cross-job `stage`, which is not currently possible though in principle such a step could be written. In the meantime, a downstream deployment job is probably the most reasonable workaround.